# Get cell to equal value from cell above

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get my cell G in my active row to equal the value of a validation list from the row above. Here's my code:

```
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Value
```

The problem is this copies the entire validation list, and I don't want that, I only want the value selected in the validation list to be copied into my cell.

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is with copy paste:

```
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).copy
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

The disadvantage of this way is that it involves the clipboard.. meaning more resources and a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to use an R1C1 formatting instead of A1. You can then reference the rows by `R[-1]C6` for getting the previous row and column G. If you don't want column G but the actual current column, instead of `R[-1]C6`, you would put `R[-1]C`.

The cell referencing style can be changed in the Options menu.

Answer (score 0):

**`PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`** is what you need. This should work:

```
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row - 1).Copy
Range("G" & ActiveCell.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```